# Perché si dice WC (vi ci) ma WWW è vu vu vu?

Tags: pronunciation

Salve,
uno studente mi ha chiesto perché nella parola WC la doppia V si pronuncia come una "vi", ma la doppia V di un sito internet è invece pronunciata "vu".
Chi mi sa spiegare il motivo?
Grazie!

Comment: Personalmente ho sempre detto e sentito “vuccì” (e vedo che il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/w-c/) conferma)...

Comment: Anch'io normalmente sento dire "vuccì", ma effettivamente sembra che esista anche la pronuncia "viccì", come in questo spot pubblicitario di WC net: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZbV2nIwBK0

Comment: Sempre sentito e detto "vicci." Potrebbero esserci varianti regionali nella pronuncia.

Comment: In teoria si dovrebbe dire “vi” per gli acronimi toscani (o toscanizzati) che  contengono una “V” e “vu” per quelli che contengono una “W”. Questo porterebbe a usare “tivì” al posto di “tivù” (o “dividì” e “viaccaesse” al posto di “divudì” e “vuaccaesse”), ma anche – cosa che solitamente sfugge – “vucì” al posto di “vicì”. - https://lituopadania.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/come-si-pronuncia-wc/

Comment: @Gio: È una “teoria” del signor Nautilus, che a quel che vedo trincia giudizi sull'Italia, la Padania (contrapposta all'Italia) e così via.

Comment: Io ho imparato l'alfabeto con “ti u vi zeta” alla fine. Considero “vu” tirannia toscana, come “scervellato” pronunciato come “scena”. `;-)`

Comment: Io sono romagnola, forse e' davvero in base alla regione! Grazie!

Comment: Quindi voi dite "tivvì" e non "tivvù"? Io sono toscano, e dico sempre "vù".

Comment: Ho veramente provato a rispondere a questa domanda, ma finora ho trovato solo [questo](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/lettera-v-si-chiama-vu) che se non altro conferma che il nome della lettera *v* varia su base regionale (non che non fosse già chiaro).

Comment: @Anon Piemonte qui: noi diciamo "Vicì". Mi sembra un'eccezione: di solito diciamo "Vu" per W ( "Vu Vu Vu punto google punto com", "Bi Emme Vu"). Diciamo anche "Tivù", ma qui non si tratta di W: si scrive "TV", non "TW"!

Answer (score 1):

Dal sito della [Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/denominazione-genere-lettere-straniere-j-k-w):

> Il fatto poi che nell'uso corrente si dica "vu vu vu" per WWW o "vu vu effe" per WWF, corrisponde al modo di pronunciare tutte le sigle entrate nell'italiano e che contengono W: da WC, a BMW, TWA, WTO per citare le più diffuse. Volendo azzardare una spiegazione a questo fenomeno, si può considerare il fatto che la lettera italiana più vicina alla W è appunto la V e, visto che le sigle non sono sempre di origine anglofona, ma possono ad esempio corrispondere a parole tedesche (come BMW in cui la W sta per Werke) dove la W si pronuncia come la nostra V, si è semplificata e unificata la pronuncia al fonema appartenente all'italiano. Questo tipo di operazione può produrre alcune ambiguità nei casi in cui si citi una sigla sconosciuta al nostro interlocutore per cui sarà necessario specificare se quella "vu" corrisponda nella grafia a W o effettivamente a V.

Dal *Dizionario Etimologico della Lingua Italiana*, Cortelazzo-Zolli:

> «s.f. o m. ‘nome della lettera v’ (1918, P.G. Goidànich, Grammatica italiana, Bologna: “Vu è il nome toscano di v; fuori di Toscana si dice vi piú spesso”; vu doppio ‘nome della lettera w’: 1918, P.G. Goidànich cit.: vu o vi doppio; 1879, TB: il doppio V).
>   Pronuncia di v fondata sul “fatto che i Romani indicavano con v anche la vocale u e che fino a poco piú di due secoli fa v ed u si scambiavano, ancora, con grande facilità” (F. Fochi, L’italiano facile, Milano, 1964, p. 23). Il n. della lettera tornò di attualità con la sempre piú frequente lettura della sigla TV ‘televisione’. Finí per prevalere la pronuncia tiv(v)ú, mentre la concorrente tiv(v)í è rimasta con valore ir. E se grammatiche e vocabolari di un tempo ammettevano le due pronunce, ora si sono ristrette esclusivamente a vu. Il vu doppio rappresenta l’ingl. double v (1580, preceduto dalla var. doble W: ca. 1465).»

Si veda anche [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-delle-prontuario-lettere_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/):

> Quanto a ‹q› e ‹v› i loro nomi, qu [kːu] e vu [vu], risentono della contiguità con la vocale ‹u›: nel primo caso per il nesso consonantico che si costituisce (quadro, qualità); nel secondo per trafila etimologica (in latino erano lettere indistinte sia sul piano fonetico sia su quello grafico e la indistinzione grafica si è protratta a lungo anche in italiano). Nel caso di vu, però, l’alternativa vi [vi] è frequente, per lo più in area settentrionale. Questa denominazione si fa sentire in alcune sigle che si sono lessicalizzate: se tiv(v)ù ha prevalso su tivì, i dvd vengono pronunciati sia [divuˈdi] sia [diviˈdi] e nel caso di Oviesse (sciolta, la sigla sta per «organizzazione vendite speciali»), la ‹v› è stata resa nella grafia non come vu ma come vi.
>
> ‹w› è chiamata universalmente doppia vu (o vu doppia), con richiamo all’aspetto del segno che è sentito come risultante dalla parziale sovrapposizione di due ‹v›. Questo segno è stato a lungo confinato a indicare (in forma maiuscola) l’esclamazione «evviva!»: W l’Italia! Ormai desueto è l’uso di indicare «abbasso» con una ‹ʍ› rovesciata; ‹w› poi ha avuto un primo revival con la diffusione di parole inglesi e di anglicismi: what, why, whisky, ecc., dove ha il valore della semiconsonante [w]; ‹w› è però presente anche in germanismi come würstel, dove corrisponde al suono [v]. Più di recente, il gergo telematico ha diffuso la formula ‹www›, pronunciata [vuvuˈvu], dove si ha vu e non doppia vu.

Comment: Potresti aggiungere qualcosa sulla variazione regionale della pronuncia? In particolare questo non aiuta a capire come mai WC sia pronunciato [vi'cci] in molte parti d'Italia (nè in quali)